# JS: timeout over function execution

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout

I have a function which returns a callback. Its execution time may vary. Is there a way to set a timeout callback over it? Or kill the function and go over with the code?

Comment: Why not use `setTimeout()` to call a function in order to read the response asynchroniously

Comment: @AlexandroPalacios I need something like ajax's timeout

Answer (score 1):

Its the game of timeouts.
Here is an example using `setTimeout` and `Promise`

```js
function executeWithin(targetFn, timeout) {
  let invoked = false;
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    targetFn().then(resolve)
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('timed out')
    }, timeout)
  })
}

executeWithin(
  // function that takes 1sec to complete
  () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('lazy fn resolved!')
    }, 1000)
  }),
  2000 // must invoke callback within 2sec
).then(console.log) 
// => lazy function is finally done!

executeWithin(
  // function that takes 3s to complete
  () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, 3000)
  }),
  2000 // must invoke callback within 2sec
).then(console.log) 
// => timed out
```